# Системные вызовы или функции WinAPI в консольных программах в С++

Tags: winapi, dos, ассемблер, c++

Всегда интересовало, как они работают.
Например я скомпилил что-то как консольный проект, скажем, в VS.
При создании окна и вызовах, будут использоваться прерыванияфункции ДОСБИОС, или же там будут WinAPI? Я имею в виду, я же могу написать на асме:

```
.model small
.data
 mes db 'Hello world$'
.stack 100h
.code
start:
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
end start
```

А могу на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
void main()
{
     std::cout<<"Hello world!"<<endl;
}
```

Что там, что там, после компиляции, на экран вылезет окошечко. Так вот, оно средствами WinAPI создается, или там что-то другое? Сами вызовы printf() std::cout<< как реализованы? На прерываниях досабиоса (консоль же) либо там тоже обертка WinAPI?

Comment: Ви есть немного путать. Никаких досабиоса под виндами нет. Есть в дос-эмуляторе. (Раньше это было dosvm, как оно называется сейчас -- не знаю). Тем более, что приведённый Вами пример нарисован для real mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы пишете консольное приложение, компилятор в заголовке exe (в так называемом PE заголовке) выставляет спецфлажок, что приложение консольное. После этого, когда приходит время запускать приложение, уже сама Windows создаст для вашего приложения "эмулятор терминала". Как он в данной Windows устроен - дело самой ОС.

Когда нужно сделать вывод на консоль, то с++ компилятор для винды просто вставит вызов WriteConsole, который умеет это делать. Никаких прерываний там нет и не будет.

Другое дело - это старый 16битный код, который ещё есть и который также хочет что то куда то выводить. Хотя файлы имеют расширение exe, внутри структура немного другая (тут уже нет pe заголовка, а только MZ). Винда, понимая это, создает похожий терминал, но все прерывания перехватывает, разбирается с ними и по возможности эмулирует.

Поэтому, хотя для пользователя код делает одно и тоже, на внутреннем уровне там две совершенно разные системы.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо Вам больше за развернутый и вразумителньый ответ!